How to read/extract the large files KNOPPIX, KNOPPIX1, KNOPPIX2 etc. from an old Knoppix installation using Ubuntu?
I have an old Knoppix installation on a HDD with encrypted user data for which I have forgotten the password, i.e. I can no longer access my data in knoppix-data.aes. Unfortunately, I also cannot remember enough of the password such that a brute-force attack would be feasible.
The HDD has two partitions SYSTEM and DATA. The latter is empty, but I noticed three very large files KNOPPIX, KNOPPIX1, and KNOPPIX2 with no filename extension  inside SYSTEM. To my understanding, these files are not encrypted.

Can I simply browse/extract their content e.g. from within Ubuntu, or are certain packages required which are exclusive to Knoppix?

Is there any chance that either one of these three files may contain at least some of the data encrypted in knoppix-data.aes (such as digital photo albums)?


Addendum: When opening the SYSTEM partition in a Linux file manager, the location is displayed as SYSTEM/KNOPPIX (in all caps). Could it be that, when the hard drive is connected, what is being mounted as SYSTEM is in fact the file KNOPPIX?

The type of encryption really matters, with defaults (of encryption) changing over time. I've successfully re-install (non-destructively too, meaning no loss of data) encrypted systems but I did know the password.  Knoppix is based on Debian, and version matters (you gave no clues) but you're off-topic here.

@guiverc There is a file kversion that contains the string 8.6.1-2019-10-14. I assume this means Knoppix version 8.6.1 installed on 14th October 2019

This question is on topic. It is about how to do something using Ubuntu.
